# I try to set DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft for my app but when run my mobile app in portrait situation it break the graphic like bellow

Tags: flutter

[when I run my app while I let my phone portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UJZz.png)
[when I run my app while I let my phone lanscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t399.png).

my code to set landscape left for my app.

```dart
void main() {
  // Step 2
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Step 3
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
  ]).then((value) => runApp(MaterialApp(home:const MyApp())));
}
```

please help me to fix this problem I expect to have results [when I run my app while I let my phone landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t399.png).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

Instead of executing step 3 before the you execute the runApp, use the `SystemChrome.setPreferrerdOrientation([])` method inside `MyApp()` `initState(){}` or in `build(){}` method, then `dispose()` it:

For Example:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    ]);
    super.initState();
  }
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

I hope this works :)